# How can i access a Value in an Array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How is it possible to access the values inside an array? i have already checked the jQuery documentation but my scenario isn't listed.

Array Structure:

```
var myData = [{
    label: "erster",
    id: 0,
    Name: "Ein Name"
}, {
    label: "zweiter",
    id: 1,
    Name: "Der zweite Name"
}, {
    label: "dritter",
    id: 2,
    Name: "Dritter Name"
}];
```

And here is my try to show up some results in the browser:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(myData, function (i, val) {
        alert(i + " " + val);
    });
});
```

The Response is no value just `Object,Object`. I think I understand the structure of `$.each` a little bit (thanks to the documentation) but I see no way to go *inside* one of this array's elements.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

#

Ok thanks a lot for those very good and clear inputs.
Now i understand how to access the values. Can someone offer me a trick how to create an HTML Output for those Elements?

Result should be something like:

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>'val.labelfromelement1'</h3>
  <div class="notimportant">'val.Namefromelement1'</div>
  <h3>'val.labelfromelement2'</h3>
  <div class="notimportant">'val.Namefromelement2'</div>
  <h3>'val.labelfromelement3'</h3>
  <div class="notimportant">'val.Namefromelement3'</div>
  <h3>'val.labelfromelement4'</h3>
  <div class="notimportant">'val.Namefromelement4'</div>
</div>
```

as you can see, it should result in an accordion that will be automatic increase if a we create a new element in the array (The Array is from a chart)

[image: Project should looks like]

With the following Code it shows me just the last instance / Part / Segment / what ever :-)

```js
var myData = [
   {
    label: "erster",
    id: 0,
    Name:"Ein Name"
    
    },
   {
    label: "zweiter",
    id: 1,
    Name:"Der zweite Name"
    
    },
   {
    label: "dritter",
    id: 2,
    Name:"Dritter Name"
    
    }
  
  ]


$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $.each(myData, function (i, val) {
    myAccordion = "<h3>" + val.label + "</h3><div>" + val.Name + "</div>";
   });
   $("#myAccordionDiv").html(myAccordion);
  
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="myAccordionDiv">

</div>
</body>
```

*deep breathing* :-) what can i do now?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/01mv34ra/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.each` code is fine, the issue is because you're trying to append a string to an object results in type coercion to a string, hence the objects in the array are converted to `[Object object]`.

Firstly, don't append the object as a string, and secondly use the console for debugging instead (To see the console, it's normally <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(myData, function (i, val) {
        console.log(i, val);
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7bs3s0y/)

Note that to get the properties of each object within the array, you can access them from the `val` parameter in your `each()` loop:

```
$.each(myData, function (i, val) {
    console.log(val.label);
    console.log(val.id);
    console.log(val.Name);
});
```

Comment: Nice thanks Rory ;)can you please have a look to my edited  Question? I have to create via jquery a div construct for the array... But it creates just the last group thx for help

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Re. the edit - I would start a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you loop through your data, each datum becomes val, so then you have to access val's properties.

```
$.each(myData, function (i, val) {
    console.log(val.label);
    console.log(val.id);
    console.log(val.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Object object is the string conversion of an object in js. You can call console.dir to see the whole object in the console. Try to access the single properties of your object with val.id for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the property of each value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var myData = [
   {
    label: "erster",
    id: 0,
    Name:"Ein Name"
    
    },
   {
    label: "zweiter",
    id: 1,
    Name:"Der zweite Name"
    
    },
   {
    label: "dritter",
    id: 2,
    Name:"Dritter Name"
    
    }
  
  ];

  
   $.each(myData, function (i ,val) {
       console.log(i + ',' + val.label + ', ' + val.id + ',' + val.Name);
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, the only issue is that *val* is an object. You have to access a property of your *val*, like *val.label*.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.each(myData, function (i ,val) {
            alert( i + " " + val.label );
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.each(myData, function (i ,val) {
            //You are now inside the first object. 
            //Your first object have 3 element so loop inside it.
            $.each(val, function(j, element){
                alert(j + ' ' + element);
            }
            alert( i + " " + val );
            //etc..
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to call or to know each property of your objects in array,
only inner array loop, do also loop object of current cell

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var myData = [ {
      label: "erster",
      id: 0,
      Name:"Ein Name" }, 
   {
      label: "zweiter",
      id: 1,
      Name:"Der zweite Name"

    },
    {
      label: "dritter",
      id: 2,
      Name:"Dritter Name"

    } ];

  $.each(myData, function (i ,val) {
    var tmpString = '';
    $.each(val, function(key, value) {
      tmpString += key + ' : ' + value + '\n';
    });
    alert(tmpString);
  });
});
```

working example https://jsfiddle.net/xxL5nhee/